# Preventing reviewers from viewing data belonging to other reviewers in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looking for script around the following:
Protecting a Google Sheet so that reviewers can only view data only assigned to them based on line item. For example there is consolidated sheet with has rating for employees across 5 divisions. Col A has the division name, Col B has rating and Col C has email Id of head of respective divisions. The head of division should be able to view the ratings employee wise pertaining to his division only.

Tried searching for similar issue but could not find. AlsoI have not tried writing a script as am not sure if this is possible
Please help

Comment: impossible to do in google sheets.

Comment: any other suggestion #ZigMandel

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to get the active user:

```
function LoggedInUser() {
  return Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```